# How to save a file in Bluemix server?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I deployed a servlet in Bluemix (bluemix-liberty) that saves a file (sent from UI) in the Bluemix server. I used below code but I am getting permission denied exception:

```
DiskFileItemFactory fileFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
File filesDir = new File("/");
fileFactory.setRepository(filesDir);
this.uploader = new ServletFileUpload(fileFactory);
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in uploading file. Processing of multipart/form-data request  failed. /upload_3d1b2086_152b5c954a4__8000_00000000.tmp (Permission denied)

Is there any option to get permission to save file in Bluemix or any other way to save a file in the Bluemix server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bluemix and Cloudfoundry are based on the concept of 12 factor apps. You should not be storing files on the filesystem. Use some kind of service instead (e.g. a document database or even a relational database, or amazon s3, etc). Multiple instances of your scaled application will not have access to the same files, also when restarting your app, it will be scheduled on a different container, and the files will be gone.

Comment: Here is some documentation on why not to store files on the filesystem in cloud foundry: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html. And how to do it right.

Comment: See also this question: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16880/storing-file-on-bluemix.html

Comment: Actually I debugged a little bit, the issue is not creating a file in the server. It allow me to create file if i use code like File file = new File("/tmp.wav"); The issue is it does not allow the servlet to accept the file that is uploaded from the UI. Any pointer in this?. I need to upload a audio file and need to store it at server or DB for temporary purpose.

Comment: Can you try uploading a small file (<100KB)?

Comment: If you have to spool it to disk, don't spool it to the root of the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters already pointed out, it would be better to store files using a service called by your CF App Instance. One flexible candidate would be Objectstorage Service. An example on how to store and retrieve files in Java can be found here:
https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-to-ibm-object-storage-for-bluemix-with-java/
Another approach would be to store a file as attachment in Cloudant NoSQL DB. The Bluemix Java or Node.js Cloudant Boilerplate shows this as example: https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/java-cloudant-web-starter/